# Warning when trying to extract hour from time

Tags: r, parsing, time

In R I'm trying to add some extra column with only the hours.

I have a column, named Time:

```
 09:30
 09:45
 10:00 
 10:40
```

And I want an extra column:

Hours:

```
 9
 9
 10
 10
```

The column Time is from the type "factor". When I try this:

```
library(lubridate)
data$hour <- hour(hm(c(data$Time)))
```

I get a warning:

```
Warning message:
In .parse_hms(..., order = "HM", quiet = quiet):
  some strings failed to parse
```

I do not understand why it is going wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could also try `as.integer(gsub(":.*", "", data$Time))` without `lubridate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `c()` call from `hour(hm(c(data$Time)))`.

By wrapping `data$Time` with `c()`, you are forcing the factor drop its attributes. This results in only its integer values, and in turn fails to parse when passed to `hm()`.

```
x <- factor(c("09:30", "09:45", "10:00", "10:40"))

## everything is fine
x    
# [1] 09:30 09:45 10:00 10:40
# Levels: 09:30 09:45 10:00 10:40

## wrapped with c() --> attributes dropped
c(x) 
# [1] 1 2 3 4

## wrapped with c() --> attributes dropped --> parsing fails
lubridate::hm(c(x))  
# [1] NA NA NA NA
# Warning message:
# In .parse_hms(..., order = "HM", quiet = quiet) :
#   Some strings failed to parse

## remove c() --> everything is fine
lubridate::hm(x)
# [1] "9H 30M 0S"  "9H 45M 0S"  "10H 0M 0S"  "10H 40M 0S"
```

So just change your code to

```
data$Time <- hour(hm(data$Time))
```